# Animation issues using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm animating a div to left by 0px by clicking on the div colored in red. Below the div , classes are added to li's as the div moves along, but the classes gets added to only certain li's and not all.

Is there any other logic to fix this ?

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/AsfFQ/16/

Below is the image of the issue
[image]

Comment: One note, this code doesn't seem to work at all in IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/AsfFQ/20/)**.

```
var pos;
var timer, selectLi = (function() {
    var $block = $('.block'),
        $container = $('.container'),
        $lis = $('.container ul li'),
        liWidth = $lis.width(),
        $selectedLi;
    return function() {
        pos = $block.offset().left - $container.offset().left;
        liNum = Math.round(pos / liWidth);
        // $selectedLi && $selectedLi.removeClass('selected');
        $selectedLi = $($lis.get(liNum));
        $('li.eligible').each(function() {
            if ($block.offset().left-3 <= $(this).offset().left) $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
    };
})();

$('.block').click(function() {
    timer = setInterval(selectLi, 30);
    $(this).animate({
        left: 0
    }, function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});

$('li').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('eligible');
    if ($(this).offset().left > $('.block').offset().left) $(this).removeClass('eligible');
});​
```

This sets the eligible list items and then as the bar moves, compares their position to tjat of the bar and if they're in range, they get the class added.

Comment: dropping to 0 still has the issue..either 1 or 2 li's are not selected. But this doesn't happen everytime.

Comment: Hmmm, seems to work fine here. Maybe my machine is faster than yours.

Comment: hmm may be but is there something which can be done for this..its driving me nuts

Comment: Is changing the duration of the animation an option?

Comment: well changing the duration seems to fix the issue only on certain times..and i'm not concerned about the value of the animation, anything should be ok

Comment: With the exception of the first list item, how does this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/AsfFQ/19/

Comment: OK I also found a way to account for that firs item. BTW in your original code `$container.offset().left` is always zero. I'll post my updated answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Your little animation needs only a little code.
See [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/creativecouple/ZA5Er/)

```
var $block = $('.block'),
    start = $block.offset().left;

$block.one('click').animate({left: 0})
 .$('li').filter(function(){return $(this).offset().left<=start})
 .repeat(30).filter(function(){return $(this).offset().left>=$block.offset().left})
 .addClass('selected').unrepeat();
​
```

I'm using this plugin [jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/).

---

This also works when animating 100px on each click, see [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/creativecouple/eEH9Z/):

```
var $block = $('.block');
$block.on('click').animate({left: '-=100px'})
 .$('li').filter(function(){return $(this).offset().left<=$block.offset().left})
 .repeat(30).filter(function(){return $(this).offset().left>=$block.offset().left})
 .addClass('selected').unrepeat();
```

Have fun!